# Visual Studio Color Codes?

Tags: visual-studio, colors, hex, color-codes

I'm trying to change the color manually to my liking.

Default looks somewhat like this:

```
<Item Background="0x02000000" BoldFont="No" Foreground="0x008CFAF1" Name="XML Attribute Quotes" />
```

So I want to change the Foreground, but I don't quite understand the format of the Color Code.

When I search hexadecimal color codes, they're 6 digits. For example: https://peteroupc.github.io/html3dutil/tutorial-colors.html

So Is it right to just add "0x00" in front of that? Seemingly all Colors I want to change start with that anyways. As far as I can tell only exception would be a default value starting with 0x02.

Comment: My page refers to HTML and CSS color codes, which are not necessarily the kind of codes that seem to be used here by Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You don't need to do any conversion with these, as they are already hex (actual code hex, not the #... web stuff). To "convert" a web hex triplet, just remove the # and prepend 0x00 and you should be good. All the other characters remain the same (case shouldn't matter, though some people like uppercase as procedure).

-according to this: [.vssettings file (Visual Studio Settings) Color Format](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/55006402.shtml)

It says 0x02 default down below there